# Missing connection to mongod server

Tags: mongodb, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.3

hope you can help me.
I have a java application that use mongodb 2.6.7. Now i must upgrade to 4.4.0 version. During the process
I decided to implement the TLS connection and here my problems began. Connection timed out.

To simplify the work I decided to connect directly using the mongo shell. Now, this is the situation:

i have the mongod server active on a linux pc (ubuntu 20.04 - ip: 192.168.1.191, mongodb installed 4.4.0, OpenSSL installed 1.1.1f), and i trying to connect with a windows 10 pc (2004 version - ip: 192.168.1.193, mongodb installed 4.4.0, OpenSSL installed 1.1.1g).
I created a self signed certificate with this commands:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:qwer -out ./demoCA/private/cakey.pem 4096

openssl req -new -x509 -days 730 -key ./demoCA/private/cakey.pem -passin pass:qwer -out ./demoCA/cacert.pem -subj '/C=LL/ST=lin/L=lin/O=lin/OU=lin/CN=lin' -outform PEM
cp ./demoCA/cacert.pem ./demoCA/certs/00.pem
cd ./demoCA/certs
ln -s 00.pem `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in 00.pem`.0
cd ..
cd ..
openssl genrsa -out ./private_key.pem 4096
openssl req -new -key ./private_key.pem -out ./request.pem -subj '/C=LL/ST=lin/L=lin/O=lin/OU=lin/CN=192.168.1.191' -outform PEM

openssl ca -in ./request.pem  -passin pass:qwer

cp ./demoCA/newcerts/01.pem ./demoCA/certs/01.pem
cd ./demoCA/certs
ln -s 01.pem `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in 01.pem`.0
cd ..
cd ..
cat ./private_key.pem ./demoCA/certs/01.pem > ./certificate.pem
```

then i started mongod with this command:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

here the mongod.conf:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 192.168.1.191
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: [ABSOLUTE_PATH]/certificate.pem
    CAFile: [ABSOLUTE_PATH]/demoCA/cacert.pem

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

i downloaded on my Win pc certificate.pem and cacert.pem and tried to connect with:

```
mongo --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile c:\ssl-cert-lin\certificate.pem --tlsCAFile c:\ssl-cert-lin\cacert.pem -u root -p test --authenticationDatabase mydb --host 192.168.1.191 --port 27017
```

the result:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.1.191:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.
```

After a thousand attempts, i tried to do viceversa, installing mongodb server on windows and connecting from linux to window. I followed the same procedure creating the certificate, same configuration of mongod, same connection parameters with the mongo command (after the upload of win certificate on linux). Linux mongo command connect correctly to mongod windows server.

So i tried to test connection directly by OpenSSL keeping both the mongo server (on linux and on windows) alive.
From linux (ip:192.168.1.191) i launched command:

```
root@btksrv:~# openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.193:27017 -CAfile ./ssl-cert-win/cacert.pem 
CONNECTED(00000003)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=1 C = WW, ST = win, L = win, O = win, OU = win, CN = win
verify return:1
depth=0 C = WW, ST = win, O = win, OU = win, CN = 192.168.1.193
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = WW, ST = win, O = win, OU = win, CN = 192.168.1.193
   i:C = WW, ST = win, L = win, O = win, OU = win, CN = win
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[lines removed...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = WW, ST = win, O = win, OU = win, CN = 192.168.1.193

issuer=C = WW, ST = win, L = win, O = win, OU = win, CN = win

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Client Certificate Types: RSA sign, DSA sign, ECDSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-384, 384 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2248 bytes and written 453 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: B84B0000D21B35AF457FBA576C3C1A4BD42DEC5B1DAC2FA33203DEA6E88DE4E7
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: CA4CEC4DE4AA5B67BC577CCA3DF7D5E5DF5ECEC9438592AAC9D7DDDB105E31FB8CB78DBBE962C0A90D99195ECD86FCBB
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1596710695
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
read:errno=0
```

From windows (ip:192.168.1.193) i launched command:

```
c:\>openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.191:27017 -CAfile c:\ssl-cert-lin\cacert.pem
CONNECTED(00000120)
Can't use SSL_get_servername
depth=1 C = LL, ST = lin, L = lin, O = lin, OU = lin, CN = lin
verify return:1
depth=0 C = LL, ST = lin, O = lin, OU = lin, CN = 192.168.1.191
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = LL, ST = lin, O = lin, OU = lin, CN = 192.168.1.191
   i:C = LL, ST = lin, L = lin, O = lin, OU = lin, CN = lin
 1 s:C = LL, ST = lin, L = lin, O = lin, OU = lin, CN = lin
   i:C = LL, ST = lin, L = lin, O = lin, OU = lin, CN = lin
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[lines removed...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = LL, ST = lin, O = lin, OU = lin, CN = 192.168.1.191

issuer=C = LL, ST = lin, L = lin, O = lin, OU = lin, CN = lin

---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
C = LL, ST = lin, L = lin, O = lin, OU = lin, CN = lin
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed25519:Ed448:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:Ed25519:Ed448:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3832 bytes and written 403 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 0D60B8F6140E7483DDE2D4D3B405E2C81FCC6C18C32B03DA811395A0ED9189A0
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: 10782266BDE34F8820365AD13FCB606128B410B6D9DBC31D382542E17058975030B4B472A907730AB63573FBD7E900B3
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    [lines removed...]

    Start Time: 1596711179
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: E3A023177260EC48FEF860C30FBF32986E6AA83EA897D5D4E68DD1418329B6C4
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Resumption PSK: BE969CD81BB54EFF67C1F877A29A15C40839767A145252BDD16BDC2E91242E069C8E04D4A3E3DA7D099120D78749EA12
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    [lines removed...]

    Start Time: 1596711179
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
read:errno=0
```

Looking at the last 2 code blocks i think there is a mismatch protocol... Linux use TLS 1.3 and windows use 1.2 protocol. Could this be the problem? in this case how can I solve?
Otherwise what can be the problem? (and the solution)

Thanks in advance for your help

P.s. before using mongo v4.4 i tried v4.2... same thing

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The problem was in Openssl. Linux has a preinstalled version of OpenSSL. In Windows i downloaded a installer from here: https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

the problem is that a third part compiled OpenSSL could has a different encryption.

I uninstalled OpenSSL from both Linux and Windows and downloaded the uncompiled library from https://github.com/openssl/openssl. After the compilation, i recreated the certificates and now windows mongo can connect linux mongod and viceversa